# Fill svg logo letters with video background

Tags: html, svg, video

I've used this way (you could see the codepen) to display image background in my logo letters. Now, i want to display a video instead of the image.

https://codepen.io/irawachaloco/pen/GJKLzy

```
<svg class='crop-shapes'>

    <defs>
        <pattern id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="100%" height="650">
            <image class='twombly' xlink:href="http://gastv.mx/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/jumex.jpg" x="-30" y="-30"
                width="380" height="267" />
        </pattern>

    </defs>

  <circle class='circ' cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="url(#img1)" filter="url(#sparklin)" onmouseover="evt.target.setAttribute('opacity', '0.5');"
13
onmouseout="evt.target.setAttribute('opacity','1)');"/>

  <rect x="110" y="0" width="100" height="100" stroke="black" fill="url(#img1)" filter="url(#sparklin)"/>

  <polygon x="10" points="270,0  220,100 320,100" fill="url(#img1)" filter="url(#sparklin)"/>

</svg>
```

Any idea or example ? I'm a noob with svg practices..
Thanks a lot !

Comment: Display a video using the html video element and use a clip-path to cut the letters out.

Comment: thanks @RobertLongson 
this way work fine https://codepen.io/DeeDee23/pen/vKVwzd
but not with this kind of svg implementation (with path, all my letters are in a path) :

 <path d="M31.37,78.5c-2.2,0-4.25-0.29-6.09-0.86c-1.82-0.56-3.41-1.41-4.73-2.52c-1.31-1.1-2.34-2.48-3.07-4.12
  c-0.73-1.64-1.1-3.59-1.1-5.79c0-2.38,0.47-4.47,1.39-6.21c0.92-1.73,2.31-3.18,4.14-4.32c1.87-1.16,4.23-2.03,7.03-2.59
  c2.83-0.57,6.18-0.85,9.94-0.85h4.87v-3.28c0-1.4-0.15-2.65-0.43-3.72c-0.3-1.11-0.81-2.06-1.51-2.82"/>